# No response from recv when using nonblocking socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am trying to create a portscanner in c. If the port is open, I want to get a response from the server. When I use regular blocking sockets, this works fine. For example, I know that for a certain address on my network, if I check port 80, it will return the html page to me when I call recv. I have tested this, and it works correctly every time.

However, I want to use nonblocking sockets, because sometimes certain servers will not respond and will cause the program to hang. I was able to get the nonblocking sockets to (kindof) work (the code is currently commented out below). I could see which ports were open, which were closed, and which timed out, but I was not able to get a response from the server (even though I know it should send one). What am I doing wrong?

tl;dr: When using nonblocking sockets (vs blocking), recv doesn't return any data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock, test_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char buf[MAX_LEN];
    int num_bytes;
    int err_code;
    int START_PORT = 1;
    int END_PORT = 100;

    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int opts;

    // resolve server name for its IP address, etc.
    hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (NULL == hp) {
        perror("gethostbyname");
        exit(2);
    }

    //printf("Here1\n");

    // build remote server addr/port
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    //server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));


    test_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    for(int i=START_PORT; i<=END_PORT; i++) {
        printf("Here2\n");
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //created the tcp socket
        //opts = fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
        printf("Here3\n");
        if (sock < 0)
        {
            perror("Socket()\n");
            exit(1);
        }  

        server_addr.sin_port = htons(i);

        // connect to server
        printf("Here4\n");
        err_code = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
        printf("Here5\n");

        /* ... */

        if (err_code < 0) {
            printf("Port %d: connection refused\n", i);
            //exit(3);
        } else {
            printf("Port %d:\n", i);
            memset(buf, 0, MAX_LEN);

            // Create message to send
            char message[256];
            strcpy(message, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ");
            strcat(message, argv[1]);
            strcat(message, "\r\n\r\n");

            unsigned total_bytes_sent = 0;
            num_bytes = send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
            if (num_bytes < 0) {
                perror("send");
                exit(4);
            }

            unsigned total_bytes_received = 0;
            while(1) {
                num_bytes = recv(sock, buf+total_bytes_received, MAX_LEN, 0);
                if(num_bytes <= 0){
                    break;
                }
                total_bytes_received += num_bytes;
            }

            // display received ack message
            //printf("Port %d:\n", i);
            fflush(stdout);
            write(1, buf, total_bytes_received);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Done...\n");
        }

        close(sock);
    }



    // close sock to release resource
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int sock, sock_test;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
struct hostent *hp;
char buf[MAX_LEN];
int num_bytes;
int err_code;
int START_PORT = 1;
int END_PORT = 100;
int valid = 1;

fd_set fdset;
struct timeval tv;


// resolve server name for its IP address, etc.
hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (NULL == hp) {
    perror("gethostbyname");
    exit(2);
}

// build remote server addr/port
memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);



for(int i=START_PORT; i<=END_PORT; i++) {
    sock_test = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_test < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket()\n");
        exit(1);
    }  

    fcntl(sock_test, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(i);

    connect(sock_test, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock_test, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = 3;            
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    if (select(sock_test + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

        getsockopt(sock_test, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0) {
            printf("%s:%d is open\n", argv[1], i);

            memset(buf, 0, MAX_LEN);


            // Create message to send
            char message[256];
            strcpy(message, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ");
            strcat(message, argv[1]);
            strcat(message, "\r\n\r\n");

            printf("Here6\n");

            unsigned total_bytes_sent = 0;
            num_bytes = send(sock_test, message, strlen(message), 0);

            printf("Here7\n");

            int retry = 3;
            unsigned total_bytes_received = 0;
            while(retry) {
                num_bytes = recv(sock_test, buf+total_bytes_received, MAX_LEN, 0);
                    if (0 == num_bytes)
                    {
                    /* socket has been closed by peer */            
                    break;
                    }
                    else if(-1 == num_bytes)
                    {
                    if ((EAGAIN == errno) || (EWOULDBLOCK == errno))
                    {
                            /* no data to be read on socket */
                            retry--;
                         /* wait one second */
                            sleep(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            /* other error */
                            perror("recv");
                            break;
                    }
                    }
                    else
                {
                    total_bytes_received += num_bytes;
                    }
            }

            // display received ack message
            //printf("Port %d:\n", i);
            fflush(stdout);
            write(1, buf, total_bytes_received);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Done...\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("%s:%d is closed\n", argv[1], i);
        }
    } else {
        printf("timed out\n");
        valid = 0; //set the boolean flag to false      
    }

    close(sock_test);
}



    // close sock to release resource
    close(sock_test);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are aware that in non blocking mode, socket will not wait when you use recv ? non blocking mode is not magic. Read about EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK

Comment: @Stargateur yes. I tried looping the recv until it got a message, but that clearly didn't work. I also tried setting the socket back to blocking before the recv, and that didn't seem to work either. What options do I have?

Comment: Retry "looping the recv until it got a message" should work `if (num_bytes == 0 || (num_bytes == -1 && num_bytes != EAGAIN && num_bytes != EWOULDBLOCK) { break; }`. Or use other solution with blocking mode (select, epoll, etc...).

Comment: @Stargateur Retrying if `num_bytes == 0` would be a complete waste of time. The peer has disconnected: there will never be any more data; you should stop reading and close the socket.

Comment: @EJP read his code I give this example to fit in his code, these condition will stop read loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in comments, in non-blocking mode, you have to handle cases when
server is not ready to send data.

For [man recv(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/recv)

> **Return Value**
>
> Upon successful completion, recv() shall return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recv() shall return 0. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.
>
> **Errors**
>
> The recv() function shall fail if:
>
> EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
>
> The socket's file descriptor is marked O_NONBLOCK and no data is waiting to be received; or MSG_OOB is set and no out-of-band data is available and either the socket's file descriptor is marked O_NONBLOCK or the socket does not support blocking to await out-of-band data.

Since your client may try to read before the server send something, you must
adapt your code to wait:

```
/* maximum number of retry, one second per retry */
int retry = 10;
unsigned total_bytes_received = 0;
while(retry) {
    num_bytes = recv(sock, buf+total_bytes_received, MAX_LEN, 0);
    if (0 == num_bytes)
    {
        /* socket has been closed by peer */            
        break;
    }
    else if(-1 == num_bytes)
    {
        if ((EAGAIN == errno) || (EWOULDBLOCK == errno))
        {
            /* no data to be read on socket */
            retry--;
            /* wait one second */
            sleep(1);
        }
        else
        {
            /* other error */
            perror("recv");
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        total_bytes_received += num_bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution did exactly what I need!

I'll update the OP with the working code.